# How to improve the range of an IR receiver?

Tags: technic, power-functions

I am creating a new Truck which contains two IR receivers in the front hood.

With my testing I get a range of about 6 feet (I have also noticed the small Technic motors on the IR receiver are slow when as the distance from the remote increases) until the receiver losses connection.

Is there a way to improve the connection and make the range bigger so my truck can go further than 6 feet?

Comment: Do you mean Truck instead of Trunk? And which motor are you referring to when you write "motors on the IR Receiver"?

Comment: Soory I didn't even noticed that typo :)

Comment: And the moter is the small technic motor.

Comment: Fresh batteries may help, too - ever noticed how TV remotes tend to exhibit the same behaviour with worn out batteries?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The best options to improve IR reception is to actually modify both the receiver and the remote (though the remote is more important to upgrade than the receiver).

Common modifications include replacing the transmitter/receiver element with higher range/power components (this may be at the cost of space), or adding reflectors behind the elements  to better send/capture the IR signal (aluminum foil works as a great DIY reflector for closed spaces.